# Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource and no database selected

Tags: php

can u guys help me..i still don't understand about the warning and how to fix although i look all the solution

```
    <php
    $hostname = "localhost";

    $database= "doctor";

    $username = "root";

    $password = "";

    $doktor = mysql_pconnect($hostname, $username, $password) or 

    trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR); 

    $IdCountry = isset($_POST['IdCountry']);

    $Country= isset($_POST['Country']);

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM warganegara WHERE IdWarga  = '$IdWarga'");
if(mysql_num_rows($result) >0){
while ($test = mysql_fetch_array($result) or die (mysql_error())){


}
    if (!$result) 

    {

    die("Error: Data not found..");

    }

    $Country=$test['Country'] ;

    if(isset($_POST['save']))

    {

    $Country_save = $_POST['ctry'];

    mysql_query("UPDATE country SET Country='$Country_save' WHERE IdCountry = '$IdCountry'")

    or die(mysql_error()); 

    echo "Saved!";

    header("Location: index.php");  

    }

    mysql_close($doctor);

    ?>
```

the question have been answer n thanks guys..but now the i can edit anything because the textfield come out with nothing although i click the edit for certain country

Comment: Use [mysql_select_db($database)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-select-db.php) function to select a database.

Comment: it come out with white page...

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://j.mp/Rj2iVR) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: you are missing selecting database line !! add `mysql_select_db($database);` before `$IdCountry` variable

Comment: ok i try to see if still hv that warning or error

Answer (score 0):

isset returns booleans, so your IdCountry and the like are being set to booleans not strings. Do not do the die test on result, instead do it on the query and you should be okay.

Comment: i just put it same as u said but still same..